# DSPs: Can I perform floating point division in a Xilinx DSP48?

Tags: dsp, xilinx, floating-point

I need to make a implementation of a floating point division using System Generator and I my version of System Generator don´t support the 'divider generator' so I was thinking several options to make the implementation. One is using the Xilinx DSP48 block.
Does anyone knows if is posible to make a division implementation through a DSP48 xilinx block?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which size floating point numbers? Do you mean full IEEE 754 floating point? Single precision (32 bit) or half or double precision?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know which Xilinx device you're targeting, but here's an overview page of the Xilinx DSP blocks:

- [XtremeDSP 48 Slice](https://www.xilinx.com/products/technology/dsp.html)

There's a small section about division in the Virtex 5 XtremeDSP user guide (p.74), for example:

- [Virtex-5 FPGA XtremeDSP Design Considerations](https://docs.xilinx.com/v/u/lBtYyLwRXIwFHMZboqeKKQ)

However, your best bet is to create a divider using 'coregen'. Launch 'coregen', create a new project and go to 'Math Functions -> Dividers' (the options appear depending on the target device). Then go through the wizard choosing your preferred setup.

Here's a bit more information on how to use 'coregen': 'coregen' will create a '.v' or'.vhd' instantiation file depending on the language you've chosen. It will run XST to generate a '.ncg' "blackbox" netlist so the implementation process can include it when you run 'ngdbuild'.

Now, coregen will also generate a '.xco' and '.cgp', which are the only files you actually need (in ISE version 12.x) in order to regenerate the core. In command line, do

```
coregen -p <core>.cgp -b <core>.xco
```

and you'll get the HDL instantiation and the netlist (and a bunch of other things in the process). Note that 'coregen' will generate its output where the input files are, *not* where it is invoked from, and there's no switch to indicate an output path!

Comment: Coregen is available from the version 10.x, isn´t it? My version of System Generator is 9.2.01 : (

Comment: coregen has been available from before 9.2 as far as I recall... but then you don't get new cores that were developed since the version you're using, of course. Why don't you upgrade to a newer version? Can you use WebPack at all?

Comment: upgrade my current version will cost montey, won´t it?

Comment: @Peterstone, not if you can make do with the free Xilinx tools, which are fully functions except that they limit the devices you can target. See more here: xilinx.com/tools/webpack.htm (look at the "product table" to see if the device you're targeting is available through WebPack).

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but elements of a DSP48 could be used within a larger block to perform floating point division.

Answer (score 1):

Almost, you can perform floating point and it can use the DSP48. But it needs more than the DSP48. [Details here](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/floating_point_ds335.pdf).